# Fetch the questions from json in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, json

```js
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app.interview', [])
    .controller('InterviewController', InterviewController)
    .factory('Interview', Interview);
InterviewController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Interview'];
Interview.$inject = ['$http'];

function Interview($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.fetchQuestion = fetchQuestion;
    return service;

    function fetchQuestion() {
        return $http.get('/app/interview/questions.json');
    }
}
})();
```

```html
  <div class="ad-container">
    <h1 class="text-center headtext">Interview Questions</h1>
    <form name="interviewForm">
        <p></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my json

```
{
  "Q1": "What is a pointer on pointer?",
  "Q2": "Write about yourself?",
  "Q3": "write a program to find multiplication of two number?",
  "Q4": "write a program to find addition of two number?",
  "Q5": "write a program to find subtraction of two number?",
  "Q6": "write a program to find percentage?",
  "Q7": "write a program to find addition of two number?",
  "Q8": "write a program to find addition of two number?"
}
```

How to fetch a sigle question from the json and show in html?

Comment: You can use ng-repeat to fetch the questions and display it on the UI

Comment: Do you want to display single question or all of them? Also, can you post your InterviewController as well?

Comment: want to display a single question and controller is there i.e. InterviewController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Interview'];

Comment: Which single question? Your question is not specific.

Comment: Use pagination and use limit filter for 1 question while using ng-repeat

Comment: A single page will contain a single question from the json

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, a simple ng-repeat

```
<p ng-repeat="dataItem in data">{{dataItem}}</p>
```

the following snippet will give you some insights

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app.interview', [])
    .controller('InterviewController', InterviewController)
    .factory('Interview', Interview);
  InterviewController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Interview'];

  function InterviewController($scope, Interview) {
    $scope.data = {}
    $scope.showSubmit = false;
    Interview.fetchQuestion().then(function(data) {
      $scope.curentPage = 0;
      console.log(data)
      $scope.data = data;
      $scope.updateCurrentPage = function() {
        if (Object.keys($scope.data).length - 1 > $scope.curentPage) {
          $scope.curentPage++;
        } else {
          $scope.showSubmit = true;
        }
      }
    })
  };

  Interview.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

  function Interview($http, $q) {
    var service = {};
    service.fetchQuestion = fetchQuestion;
    return service;

    function fetchQuestion() {
      //return $http.get('/app/interview/questions.json');
      var data = {
        "Q1": "What is a pointer on pointer?",
        "Q2": "Write about yourself?",
        "Q3": "write a program to find multiplication of two number?",
        "Q4": "write a program to find addition of two number?",
        "Q5": "write a program to find subtraction of two number?",
        "Q6": "write a program to find percentage?",
        "Q7": "write a program to find addition of two number?"
      };
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve(data);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app.interview">
  <div class="ad-container" ng-controller="InterviewController">
    <h1 class="text-center headtext">Interview Questions</h1>
    <form name="interviewForm">
      <div ng-repeat="dataItem in data track by $index" ng-show="$index==curentPage">
        <p>{{dataItem}}</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Aswer">
      </div>
      <div ng-if="!showSubmit">
        <button ng-click="updateCurrentPage()">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="showSubmit">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, bro I did according to my JSON and working fine but at last question, the NEXT button will be changed to Submit. How it's possible?

Comment: is there any way to check a user how time spent in a single question? Means q1 took how much time and then q2 like that ?

Comment: I have added my answer, according to that, How to calculate the time, i.e. a user how much time spent in a single question to answer ?

Comment: @PadhyAkash This community is intended for providing help on errors that block your code and not for writing code based on your requirements. If you find above answer fit your question then mark it as correct and ask the new as another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="ad-container">
<h1 class="text-center headtext">Interview Questions</h1>
<form name="interviewForm" ng-if="!showSubmit">
    <p ng-bind="question['Q'+ind]"></p>
    <textarea cols="85" rows="10" placeholder="Write your answer here" ng-model="answer['Q'+ind]"></textarea>
</form>
<md-button style="float:right" class="md-raised md-primary flr8" ng-click="nextQuestion()" ng-if="!showSubmit">NEXT</md-button>
<!--<md-button style="float:right" class="md-raised md-primary flr8"  ng-if="showSubmit">SUBMIT</md-button>-->

<md-card aria-label="Obmondo" class="login-card">
    <form name="info" ng-if="showSubmit">
        <md-card-header class="color2">
            <md-card-header-text>
                <span class="md-title">AKASH</span>
            </md-card-header-text>
        </md-card-header>

        <md-card-content>
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <input name="name" ng-model="user.name" type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-required="true">
                <div ng-messages="info.name.$error" role="alert">
                    <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
                </div>
                <div ng-messages="login.email.$error">
                    <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <input name="email" ng-model="user.email" type="email" placeholder="Email (required)" ng-required="true"
                       minlength="4" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" />
                <div ng-messages="info.email.$error" role="alert">
                    <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
                        Your email must be between 4 and 100 characters long and look like an e-mail address.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-messages="info.email.$error">
                    <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <input name="phome" ng-model="user.phone" type="tel" placeholder="Phone" ng-required="true">
                <div ng-messages="info.name.$error" role="alert">
                    <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
                </div>
                <div ng-messages="info.phone.$error">
                    <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-button class="md-raised login-btn text-center" type="submit">Submit</md-button>
        </md-card-content>
    </form>
</md-card>
```

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app.interview', [])
    .controller('InterviewController', InterviewController)
    .factory('Interview', Interview);
InterviewController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Interview'];

function InterviewController($scope, Interview) {
    var originatorEv;

    $scope.ind = 1;
    $scope.question = {};

    $scope.nextQuestion = function () {
        if (Object.keys($scope.question).length-1 > $scope.ind){
            $scope.ind++;
        }else {
            $scope.showSubmit = true;
        }
    };


    Interview.fetchQuestion()
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.question = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function () {
            $scope.question = {};
        });
}

Interview.$inject = ['$http'];

function Interview($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.fetchQuestion = fetchQuestion;
    return service;
    function fetchQuestion() {
        return $http.get('/app/interview/questions.json');
    }
}
```

})();